Counting conserved quantities in quantum mechanics
In quantum mechanics, the core data is a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, a Hamiltonian $H: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$, and an algebra of observables $\mathcal{A}$. The choice data is a unitary projective representation of the algebra $\pi: \mathcal{A} \to \mathfrak{u}(\mathcal{H})$. Then, the full dynamical symmetry group of the Hamiltonian is its stabilizer in $U(\mathcal{H})$
$$S_H := \{u \in U(\mathcal{H}): uHu^{-1} =H\} = \{u\in U(\mathcal{H}):u\Lambda u^{-1}=\Lambda\}$$
where $\Lambda$ is a diagonalized $H$. Note that the stabilizer of $H$ a priori actually has nothing to do with the algebra of observables.
Note that $U(\mathcal{H})$ is a Lie group and $S_H$ is topologically closed. Then, by Cartan's theorem $S_H$ is itself a Lie group. Hence, Noether's theorem can be applied to $S_H$.
In particular, $\dim S_H$ is the number of generators (in the Lie algebraic sense) of $S_H$. This number should thus count the number of conserved quantities. Is there a systematic way to actually compute $\dim S_H$ for a generic Hamiltonian?


The claim that $\mathrm{U}(\mathcal{H})$ is a Lie group is questionable for infinite-dimensional $\mathcal{H}$ and likewise for $S_H$. Note that for $H=1$ you have $S_H=\mathrm{U}(\mathcal{H})$, so there is no guarantee for $S_H$ to be finite-dimensional. 2. In this context, it would be more usual to call $S_H$ the centralizer or commutant of $H$, and under this name you should find relevant results, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3886075/143136, https://mathoverflow.net/a/179619/157071


@ACuriousMind 1. This reference (Neeb 1997 Journal of Lie Theory) supposedly proves that $U(\mathcal{H})$ is a Banach Lie group for separable $\mathcal{H}$--which seems to be a generalization of a usual Lie group? And, is there a problem with there being a non-finite amount of conserved quantities? 2. Thank you for the more common language.

Note that the traditional Noether's theorem is for a classical system with an action formulation.
